# Linker error when adding Custom Objective-C Framework to project

Tags: ios, objective-c, compiler-errors, frameworks

I have created an Objective-C .framework file, and attempting to put into into a project. I have copied the framework from the "Debug-iphoneos" folder into the new project folder, as well as set the framework in Linked Frameworks and Libraries and Embedded Binaries. When I try to run the project containing the framework I get the error

ld: framework not found ExampleFramework
Linker Command Failed With Exit Code 1

I tried following this video, which simply builds a swift framework and adds it to a project, but this seems to require different steps for objective-c

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86cPaa3FrRg

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your build phase settings verify the path to the framework is correct and also remember to check the option to copy file if needed when importing your framework.

**Targets - Build Phases - Link Binary with Libraries**